# Get function in JQuery is doing almost nothing

Tags: jquery

I am trying to run a really simple JQuery stuff and hosted the content at http://trago.in/SD/test.html and the JSON file at http://trago.in/SD/abc.json

I have tried with jQuery and $ both, but the alerts inside the get function are not showing up. I am not that great in JQuery, so need some help here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.4.1.min.js"></script>

<script>

function drawChart() {
    jQuery.get("abc.json", function(data){
        alert("test");
        alert(data);
    });
}
</script>
<title>Morris.js Donut Chart Example</title>

<body onLoad="drawChart()">
<div id="donut-example"></div>
</body>
```

Please advice.

AJ

Comment: Almost nothing means that you will get almost no answers. No details, no help. This is how SO works.

Comment: What errors/messages do you see in the [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) when you load this page? Are you sure `abc.json` is in the correct folder?

Comment: Check your console, see abc.json at network tab: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data.`

Comment: @Silviu Burcea, Thanks for down voting a useless looking question. But the solutions below made my day.
I did not have time to frame a great question, so it was a hurriedly prepared...Anyways thanks guys for all the help...

Comment: @AJ84, nothing personal, of course. In the end, it was all about bad JSON format, so nothing to blame on jQuery. The lack of details forced me to downvote. The answers are good, provides a solution, but I don't believe that we're here to debug. Your error is common and there are a couple of solutions on Google, even the top links are on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is wrong.

i used this code on the console to test it:

```
var jqxhr = $.get( "abc.json", function() {
  alert( "success" );
}).done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
}).fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
}).always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
});
```

From the https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ website

your JSON layout should be something like this:

```
[
    {
        "y": "2011Q1",
        "item1": "2666"
    },
    {
        "y": "2011Q2",
        "item1": "2778"
    }
]
```

Atention on the double quotes.

you can use this website to validate it later:

http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            function drawChart() {
                $.get("abc.json", function (data) {
                    $(".result").html(data);
                    alert("test");
                    alert(data);
                });
            }

 });
```

Or maybe this is easier for you to understand:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var url = "http://trago.in/SD/test.html";

    var dataJson =
    [
        { y: '2011 Q1', item1: 2666 },
        { y: '2011 Q2', item1: 2778 },
        { y: '2011 Q3', item1: 4912 },
        { y: '2011 Q4', item1: 3767 },
        { y: '2012 Q1', item1: 6810 },
        { y: '2012 Q2', item1: 5670 },
        { y: '2012 Q3', item1: 4820 },
        { y: '2012 Q4', item1: 15073 },
        { y: '2013 Q1', item1: 10687 },
        { y: '2013 Q2', item1: 8432 }
    ];

    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",
        url: url,
        data: { data: dataJson },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("test");
            alert(data);
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://trago.in/SD/abc.json',
  data: "param=no",
  success:function(html){
    // successful request; do something with the data
    $.each(html, function(key, value){
       $('html').append(value.y+"-"+value.item1);
    });
  },
  error:function(){
    // failed request;
    alert("error");
  }
});
```